# How to split a string in Java when there is a space?

Tags: java, regex, string

All I want to do is split a string when there is a space. for example, if the input is:

```
5 10
```

the array should be ["5", "10"]

I tried this:

```
  Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
  String[] inputs = input.split("\\p{Space}");
  System.out.println(inputs[0]);
  System.out.println(inputs[1]);
```

However only the 5 turns up and then there is an array out of bounds error.

Edit: sorry, I was an idiot. I used: scn.next() instead of scn.nextLine()

Comment: Where do you assign `input`?  Are you sure it's what you think it is?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This has the same problem. I tried your method first

Comment: Show us how you get `input`.

Comment: Note that `split("\\p{Space}")` should have worked fine, but may be unnecessarily verbose.  It's frustrating that so many people posted answers that don't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer works

```
text.split(" "); // to split on a single space character
```

but it seems like you are not getting the input you say you are.

You seem to be using `Scanner#next()` which returns a single token, where a token is delimited by whitespace (a space character is a whitespace character), instead of `Scanner#nextLine()` which will go to the end of the line, ie. look for a `\n` (or `\r\n`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just by:

```
text.split(" ");
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem `\\p{Space}` represents also space so `split(" ")` has no right to work if `split("\\p{Space}");` doesn't work.

Comment: This is the correct answer and was given first so should be accepted.

Comment: @reor No, if split on `\\p{Space}` didn't work then it is impossible that split on `" "` will work since `" "` is part of `\\p{Space}`. This answer can't solve anything. It is simplification but not solution. All answers which only suggest split on `" "` or `\\s` are **not** solve solutions of OP real problem.

Comment: @Pshemo Except the split on `\\p{Space}` does work.  The user was having a problem with something else but he thought the `split` statement wasn't working.  So `" "` is actually the correct answer because `\\p{Space}` is uselessly obtuse and verbose.

Comment: @reor So you agree that OP real problem was not split, but something else. Which is why this answer is not solution of **real** problem here. As I said, it is only simplification of needed code.

Comment: @Pshemo Correct, this answer isn't the solution to the OP's problem.  But it is the solution to the **question asked** and hence should be marked as such (ie. accepted).  To be honest I think the entire question should be deleted.

Comment: @reor If by **question asked** you mean question from title then you would be right, but you need to remember that title is only part of question. It is entire post which is description of problem OP wants to find solution, and that description clearly mentioned that OP already tried `split("\\p{Space}")` but it didn't work as it should so suggesting `split(" ")` only answers question from title, but doesn't solve **the** problem. That is why I believe that people shouldn't post only `split(" ");` variant as solution, since it doesn't solve anything. Instead they should ask OP for more details

Comment: @reor That is why instead of answering people should vote to put this question on hold until OP would post more details which would let us reproduce his/her problem (deleting question is a bit too extreme in this case IMO).

Comment: I agree here with @Pshemo the question is incomplete and should have added more information. The code I provide is the simplier answer to the question as reor said. But I also agree that the answer that should be accepted is the one from Sotirius even if it is dealing with some info that wasn't provided on the question.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
input.split("\\s+");
```

This will split not only "5 10" to "5" and "10", but will split by any number of whitespaces. For example, if you have 4 whitespaces between 5 and 10 the output will be the same.

or you can use simply " " to ignore tabs and line breaks.

Comment: This would get also Tabs and Enters characters.

Comment: Added info about that.

Comment: One question: Can you explain exactly how using `\\s+` instead of `\\p{Space}` could it solve OP problem? Space belongs to `\\s` and `\\p{Space}`. Notice that question is about "array out of bounds error" which means that split didn't happened, and OP can't access `inputs[1]` element (since split returns always at least original string `inputs[0]` always exist so this can't cause exception).

Comment: Id doesn't. It's like: "You are using xyz. I don't know much about how xyz works, but I know abc will work for that, so use abc." I usually don't use \\p{Space} and though that could cause a problem and I wouldn't notice it, since I'm not used to that syntax. Just though that as I know this method works, I should point that out. They are, indeed the same.

Answer (score 0):

just do  this:

```
input.split(" ");
```

Comment: Take a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147177/how-to-split-a-string-in-java-when-there-is-a-space/24147246#comment37262789_24147197)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I was an idiot. I used:
scn.next() instead of scn.nextLine()

Comment: Please update your question with the discovered information or delete it.

Comment: You should probably accept this answer as solution. People are ready to think that there is case where `split(" ");` work while `split("\\p{Space}");` is not.

Comment: Actually Sotirios [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24147246/1393766) your question correctly explaining also possible problem with `next` so probably his answer should be accepted with comment that `next` was indeed the problem, and this answer should be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

change "\p{Space}"  to " " or "\s+"

Comment: Can you explain how this change could solve OP problem?

Comment: I had posted my response before his edit. It was a GIGO scenario.

Comment: Which comment? If the one explaining problem with `next` then this doesn't make your answer appropriate. `\\p{Space}` includes also `" "` so using it as split parameter doesn't have right to work if split on `\\p{Space}` didn't work. Same about `\\s`.

Comment: Provided the supplied information was the issue, that is the only possibility. I have never seen 'Space' used in a Java regex, but I am 100% positive that in Java " " and "\\s" work for what he needs.  That is was makes it a GIGO scenario.

Answer (score -1):

If there are multiple space between two words use this:

> `text.split("\\s+");`

if input is

> `5  10 15`

then the output will be

> `"5","10","15"`

Comment: What are you trying to say here? That split on `\\s` should work while on space `\\p{Space}` not? Can you explain what problem this change solves? From what I see `\\s` just adds other whitespaces like tabs and line separators which is unnecessary here.